# What does the colon (:) operator do?

Tags: java, for-loop, foreach, operators

Apparently a colon is used in multiple ways in Java. Would anyone mind explaining what it does?

For instance here:

```
String cardString = "";
for (PlayingCard c : this.list)  // <--
{
    cardString += c + "\n";
}
```

How would you write this `for-each` loop a different way so as to not incorporate the `:`?

Comment: Others have already mentioned that such case is a for-each loop. For a more detailed explanation of how it works, see http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html

Answer (score 222, accepted):

There are several places colon is used in Java code:

1. Jump-out label ([Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/branch.html)):

   ```
   label: for (int i = 0; i < x; i++) {
       for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
           if (something(i, j)) break label; // jumps out of the i loop
       }
   } 
   // i.e. jumps to here
   ```
2. Ternary condition ([Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html)):

   ```
   int a = (b < 4)? 7: 8; // if b < 4, set a to 7, else set a to 8
   ```
3. For-each loop ([Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html)):

   ```
   String[] ss = {"hi", "there"}
   for (String s: ss) {
       print(s); // output "hi" , and "there" on the next iteration
   }
   ```
4. Assertion ([Guide](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/language/assert.html)):

   ```
   int a = factorial(b);
   assert a >= 0: "factorial may not be less than 0"; // throws an AssertionError with the message if the condition evaluates to false
   ```
5. Case in switch statement ([Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html)):

   ```
   switch (type) {
       case WHITESPACE:
       case RETURN:
           break;
       case NUMBER:
           print("got number: " + value);
           break;
       default:
           print("syntax error");
   }
   ```
6. Method references ([Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html))

   ```
   class Person {
      public static int compareByAge(Person a, Person b) {
          return a.birthday.compareTo(b.birthday);
      }}
   }

   Arrays.sort(persons, Person::compareByAge);
   ```

Comment: nice - I missed a few! and I didn't even know you can name assertions like that, very useful.

Comment: Coming from .NET (C#), the closest analogy for the structure in question would be the for-each, which you explained in a good manner.

Comment: A failed `assert` does not "quit the program".  It throws an `AssertionError`.  It will only cause the program to exit if it is thrown on the stack of the only remaining non-daemon thread ... and not caught.

Comment: if you aim to include all, then I would add double colon (::) operator

Comment: Also, a double colon is used in method references.

Comment: What about in this code segment? `+ equals(object2:Stock) : boolean`

Comment: The first example - jump-out label - seems to br a semicolon rather than a colon.

Answer (score 35):

There is no "colon" operator, but the colon appears in two places:

1: In the ternary operator, e.g.:

```
int x = bigInt ? 10000 : 50;
```

In this case, the ternary operator acts as an 'if' for expressions. If bigInt is true, then x will get 10000 assigned to it. If not, 50. The colon here means "else".

2: In a for-each loop:

```
double[] vals = new double[100];
//fill x with values
for (double x : vals) {
    //do something with x
}
```

This sets x to each of the values in 'vals' in turn. So if vals contains [10, 20.3, 30, ...], then x will be 10 on the first iteration, 20.3 on the second, etc.

Note: I say it's not an operator because it's just syntax. It can't appear in any given expression by itself, and it's just chance that both the for-each and the ternary operator use a colon.

Comment: second half helped, this should be the real answer

Comment: +1 for the more verbose explanation of what it's doing in for-each loop.

Answer (score 21):

Just to add, when used in a for-each loop, the ":" can basically be read as "in".

So

```
for (String name : names) {
    // remainder omitted
}
```

should be read "For each name IN names do ..."

Answer (score 16):

> How would you write this for-each loop a different way so as to not incorporate the ":"?

Assuming that `list` is a `Collection` instance ...

```
public String toString() {
   String cardString = "";
   for (Iterator<PlayingCard> it = this.list.iterator(); it.hasNext(); /**/) {
      PlayingCard c = it.next();
      cardString = cardString + c + "\n";
   }
}
```

---

I should add the pedantic point that `:` is not an operator in this context.  An operator performs an operation in an expression, and the stuff inside the `( ... )` in a `for` statement is not an expression ... according to the JLS.

Comment: My question is: why? Why doing the same thing the long way?

Comment: @RichN - he doesn't want to do it, he just wants to know how.

Comment: not homework, I want to know how to do it the long way so I can understand the logic

Comment: Actually in my (bad) university, during computer engineering studies, they never taught us anything about the (:) in the java course, I came to learn it later by watching examples, and unfortunately, it is hard for me now to code it into my mind since I did all the projects in the uni the long way

Comment: You don't need to assume that `list` is an instance of `Collection`; it must be an instance of `Iterable` if it is able to be used in the enhanced for loop, meaning it will have the `iterator()` method that you call on it in your answer.

Comment: Fair enough, but in the context of the question,  it is highly unlikely that it will be some custom / 3rd party class that doesn't extend `Collection`.  (A more likely case would be will be an array ... where this won't work!)

Answer (score 1):

It's used in for loops to iterate over a list of objects.

```
for (Object o: list)
{
    // o is an element of list here
}
```

Think of it as a `for <item> in <list>` in Python.

Answer (score 1):

You usually see it in the ternary assignment operator;

Syntax

```
variable =  `condition ? result 1 : result 2;`
```

example:

```
boolean isNegative = number > 0 ? false : true;
```

which is "equivalent" in nature to the if else

```
if(number > 0){
    isNegative = false;
}
else{
    isNegative = true;
}
```

Other than examples given by different posters,

you can also use : to signify a label for a block which you can use in conjunction with continue and break..

for example:

```
public void someFunction(){
     //an infinite loop
     goBackHere: { //label
          for(int i = 0; i < 10 ;i++){
               if(i == 9 ) continue goBackHere;
          }
     }
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but that is an awful example. Why wouldn't you write 
boolean isNegative = number > 0;

Ternary conditions are good for things such as 
double sgn = number>0 ? 1 :0;

Comment: @user44242 lol yes i don't even remember why I gave that example.

Comment: @user44242 Showing an example like that keeps it simple and better shows how the conditional operator works. "*Why wouldn't you write boolean isNegative = number > 0;*" Because that doesn't demonstrate anything about the ternary operator.

Answer (score 1):

In your specific case,

```
String cardString = "";
for (PlayingCard c : this.list)  // <--
{
    cardString = cardString + c + "\n";
}
```

`this.list` is a collection (list, set, or array), and that code assigns `c` to each element of the collection.

So, if `this.list` were a collection {"2S", "3H", "4S"} then the `cardString` on the end would be this string:

```
2S
3H
4S
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. How could this code be rewritten to not use the ":" ?

Answer (score 0):

It is used in the new short hand for/loop

```
final List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
for (final String s : list)
{
   System.out.println(s);
}
```

and the ternary operator

```
list.isEmpty() ? true : false;
```

Comment: I didn't realize it was that new... when did it come in?

Comment: @Mechko, in Java 5: http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/relnotes/features.html#forloop

Comment: oh... that was 6 years ago... Not new by my frame of reference :D

Comment: I'm with piggles - six years means it's been around since practically the dawn of time.

Answer (score 0):

The colon actually exists in conjunction with `?`

```
int minVal = (a < b) ? a : b;
```

is equivalent to:

```
int minval;
if(a < b){ minval = a;} 
else{ minval = b; }
```

Also in the for each loop:

```
for(Node n : List l){ ... }
```

literally:

```
for(Node n = l.head; n.next != null; n = n.next)
```

Answer (score 0):

It will prints the string"something" three times.

```
JLabel[] labels = {new JLabel(), new JLabel(), new JLabel()};                   

for ( JLabel label : labels )                  
 {              
   label.setText("something");  

 panel.add(label);             
 }
```

Comment: this is what said above as ForEach loop

Answer (score 0):

Since most for loops are very similar, Java provides a shortcut to reduce the 
   amount of code required to write the loop called the for each loop.

Here is an example of the concise for each loop:

```
for (Integer grade : quizGrades){
      System.out.println(grade);
 }
```

In the example above, the colon (:) can be read as "in". The for each loop 
   altogether can be read as "for each Integer element (called grade) in 
   quizGrades, print out the value of grade."

Answer (score -1):

colon is using in for-each loop,
Try this example,

```
import java.util.*;

class ForEachLoop
{
       public static void main(String args[])
       {`enter code here`
       Integer[] iray={1,2,3,4,5};
       String[] sray={"ENRIQUE IGLESIAS"};
       printME(iray);
       printME(sray);

       }
       public static void printME(Integer[] i)
       {           
                  for(Integer x:i)
                  {
                    System.out.println(x);
                  }
       }
       public static void printME(String[] i)
       {
                   for(String x:i)
                   {
                   System.out.println(x);
                   }
       }
}
```