# instanceof in java

Tags: java, instanceof

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Java: What does the colon (:) operator do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2399590/java-what-does-the-colon-operator-do)

```
for (CreditCard cc : credit1)
```

&

```
if (index instanceof RewardCard)
```

is ":" and instanceof the same? so I could use?

```
if (index : RewardCard)
```

or

```
for (CreditCard cc instanceof credit1)
```

if not, can someone explain what the ":" mean?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They're not the same: `instanceof` checks if an instance of an Object is of a certain type. The `:` in `for (CreditCard cc : credit1)` is a short way to loop through a List (`foreach` loop).

Answer (score 3):

Not at all, they are completely different.

- `for (.. : ..)` is a [for-each loop](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html)
- `instanceof` checks the runtime type

Answer (score 1):

```
for (CreditCard cc : credit1)
```

it means

```
for each CreditCard IN credit1, lets call it cc and use it somehow
```

and you can use class CreditCard if only it is the same as class declared for given collection.

```
    List<Parent> list = new ArrayList<Parent>();
    list.add(new Parent());
    list.add(new Child());

    for (Child parent : list) { // compilation error!  - Type mismatch: cannot convert from element type Parent to Child
        System.out.println(parent);
    }
```

So `instanceof` and `for (SomeType obj : SomeCollection)` are not even close to be similar