# Java Conditional Operator : from AP Computer Science Exam

Tags: java

I just started Java once again after a two months of iOS development. I decided to refresh my memory with the AP Computer Science Exam. Problem is I ran into a conditional operator that looks familiar but I can't find it anywhere online. Here's the code:

```
for (Card card : myDeck)
    System.out.println(card);
```

What I don't understand is the `:` operator. I already know the `?:` operators function, but I'm not sure how the singular `:` works alone? Any feedback I'd fully appreciate, thanks for your time.

Comment: http://www.leepoint.net/notes-java/flow/loops/foreach.html

Answer (score 1):

It's a for-each loop. Basically, if myDeck is some type of Collection, like an ArrayList, then it iterates over the collection.

You can find several examples online, but here's one that should help.

[Java: What does the colon (:) operator do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2399590/java-what-does-the-colon-operator-do)

Answer (score 0):

It's called an enhanced `for` loop. The first part, `Card card`, says that the current version of `Card` of this iteration is going to be called `card`.  The second part, `myDeck`, is the array of `Cards` that you are iterating through.

https://blogs.oracle.com/CoreJavaTechTips/entry/using_enhanced_for_loops_with