# Meaning of "this" in this code?

Tags: java, oop

```
 public boolean contains(Object o) {
    for (E x : this)
        if (x.equals(o))
            return true;
    return false;
}
```

Can someone tell me what excatly means "this" in this code? Can I write it without this and how?

Comment: simply put, the second argument (after `:`) in that enhanced for loop is anything which is an `Iterable<E>`.  Your current instance (`this` during the `#contains` method) is an instance of an `Iterable<E>` in this case.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the meaning of "this" in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3728062/what-is-the-meaning-of-this-in-java)

Comment: There are possibly 2 questions here - [what the `E x : ...` for-loop does](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2399590/java-what-does-the-colon-operator-do), and then [what the `this` refers to](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3728062/what-is-the-meaning-of-this-in-java) (and how to rewrite it without `this`, which should become obvious if you understand the code)

Comment: Awkward. I want to close as a duplicate, but the candidate duplicate from 2010 has no accepted answer ... :/ .

Answer (score 22):

Here `this` represents object on which current method was invoked. For instance if you have `a.contains(x)` then inside `contains` method `this` will return reference to same object as held in `a` reference variable.

Since you ware able to use `this` in for-each it means that `contains` method is placed in class which implements `Iterable<E>` interface because for-each can iterate only over:

- arrays like `String[] array = ...; for(String s : array){...}`
- instances of classes which implement `Iterable<E>` like `List<String>` where we can write `for(String s : list){...}`

To avoid `this` you can explicitly add to your method parameter of class which contains this method, like

```
public boolean contains(YourClass yc, Object o) {

//and use that parameter in loop instead of `this`

    for (E x : yc)
        if (x.equals(o))
            return true;
    return false;
}
```

but this means you would need to call such method in a way `a.contains(a,x)` so it needs to repeat `a` twice (not to mention it can allow us to pass other instance of our class than `a` like `a.contains(b,x)`).

To avoid this repetition we can make `contains` method `static` which will allow to invoke it via `YourClass.contains(a,x)`. But this way we need to resign from one of basic OOP concepts - polymorphism - since it doesn't work with `static` methods.

Compiler solves it using first solution, so it compiles our methods like they would be written (and we actually CAN write methods that way) as

```
public boolean contains(YourClass this, Object o) {
//                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    ...
}
```

Then when we write `a.contains(x)` it is compiled as if we would invoke `a.contains(a,x)`.

Comment: Major upvote about the `this` argument included in the parameter list. Didn't know you could do that

Comment: @Rogue It, like many things, is a Java simplification of a C++ workaround to a C limitation, I believe.  Long story short, in C++, the compiler essentially translates member functions into freestanding functions, where `this` is the implicitly-passed first parameter; given class type `class C { public: void f() {} };` and instance `C c`, the compiler will essentially translate member `C::f()` into freestanding `void C_f(C* const this) {}`, and call `c.f()` into `C_f(&c)`.  Unlike C++, Java seems to allow the programmer to manually specify `this` in the parameter list.

Comment: (This is because the original C++ compiler actually cross-compiled C++ code into C code.  Since C doesn't allow `struct`s to have member functions, the C++ compiler had to turn them into freestanding functions; since they needed to be tied to a specific instance, they had to take that instance as a parameter (which had to be implemented as a pointer, both because C didn't have references, and because I don't believe references were added to the language until after `this`' syntax was finalised).  It ends up looking like [this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/791690f6485777a2).)

Comment: (The names will be more complex than `C::f` turning into `C_f`, though, but name mangling isn't relevant to this.)

Comment: Wow, I didn't know you could explicitly pass `this` as a parameter. There is an explanation [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.1) to why this feature exists: to allow the annotation of `this`.

Answer (score 5):

`this` is a object of the class that contains your `contains()` method. It refers to the object of that class for which the method is executed.

Putting it after the `:` of an enhanced for loop means that the class that contains this method must implement `Iterable<E>`, since the enhanced for loop can be used to iterate over either arrays or instances of classes that implement the `Iterable` interface. This means your class is able to iterate over some collection of `E` elements. `E` is probably a generic type parameter`.

In order to write your method without `this`, you would have to supply a reference to some alternative object that implements `Iterable<E>`, but I don't see the point of doing that.

Answer (score 4):

> What exactly means `this` in this code?

**It is always a reference to the current instance.** I assume your class implements the [`Iterable<T>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Iterable.html) interface and overrides the [`Iterator<T> iterator()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Iterable.html#iterator--) method from it.

The loop is just a syntax sugar for the enhanced `for` statement. According to the specification ([§14.14.2.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#d5e21297)):

> ```
> for ({VariableModifier} UnannType VariableDeclaratorId : Expression)
>     Statement
> ```
>
> **The type of the Expression must be Iterable or an array type (§10.1), or a compile-time error occurs.**
>
> If the type of `Expression` is a subtype of `Iterable`, then the translation is as follows.
>
> If the type of `Expression` is a subtype of `Iterable<X>` for some type argument `X`, then let `I` be the type `java.util.Iterator<X>`; otherwise, let `I` be the raw type `Iterator`.
>
> The enhanced for statement is equivalent to a basic for statement of the form:
>
> ```
> for (I #i = Expression.iterator(); #i.hasNext(); ) {
>     {VariableModifier} TargetType Identifier = (TargetType) #i.next();
>     Statement
> }
> ```

Usually, a class implements the `Iterable` to provide to an API user the ability of being allowed to iterate over the internal collection hiding the actual implementation.

> Can I write it without this and how?

1. Use the logic you have written for the inner iterator.
2. Use the implementation of the underlying collection (if it's and it suits).
3. Choose one of the options mentioned above and rewrite into a standard `for`.

Answer (score 1):

Keyword `this` is just a reference to the current object.

Here is a example how can be `this` used:

```
public class Person {
    public final String name;

    public Person(String name) {
        // name = name; 
        // which one is an argument, and which one is class field? 
        // by default, both are reference on argument

        // using "this" to access class field
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void copyFields(Person other) {
        // current object's reference is the same as other object reference 
        // in other words "this" and "other" are the same instances 
        // example: 
        // Person p1 = new Person("a");
        // Person p2 = p1; // p2 is now pointing on the same memory address
        //                 // as p1, so both are pointing on the same object
        //                 // stored in memory.
        // p1.copyFields(p2);
        if (this == other) { // copying from self? useless...
            return;
        }
        this.name = other.name;
    }
}
```

Anything that implements `Iterable` interface has method which returns `Iterator` instance, which is **implicitly used by foreach loop to iterate over items hold by object**. Iterator 
has methods `hasNext()` which returns `true`, if there is another object 
in iterable container, relative to current position, and `next()` which returns 
next `object` or throws `NoSuchElementException` if there is no next object (last invokation of `hasNext()` has returned `false`).

Here is a simple example of `Iterable` implementation with `contains` methods:

```
public class Customer extends Person implements Iterable<Item> {
    private final List<Item> list = new LinkedList<>();
    public final String name;

    public Customer(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void add(Item item) {
        list.add(item);
    }

    // implementing iterable interface

    @Override
    public Iterator<Item> iterator() {
        return list.iterator();
    }

    // some contains implementations

    public boolean contains1() {
        for (Item item : this) { // customer implements Iterable = OK
            if (o.equals(item)) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    public boolean contains2() {
        for (Item item : list) { // list implements Iterable = OK
            if (o.equals(item)) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    public boolean contains3(Object o) {
        for (Iterator<Item> iter = iterator(); iter.hasNext();   ) {
            Item item = iter.next();
            if (o.equals(item)) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    public boolean contains4(Object o) {
        for (Iterator<Item> iter = list.iterator(); iter.hasNext();   ) {
            Item item = iter.next();
            if (o.equals(item)) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    public boolean contains5(Object o) {
        Iterator<Item> iter = iterator(); 
        while (iter.hasNext()) {
            Item item = iter.next();
            if (o.equals(item)) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    public boolean contains6(Object o) {
        Iterator<Item> iter = list.iterator();
        while (iter.hasNext()) {
            Item item = iter.next();
            if (o.equals(item)) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    public boolean contains7(Object o) {
        return list.contains(o);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Methods are defined in *`classes`*, not in *`objects`*.

But they are (generally) invoked from *`objects`*.

Methods - as they are defined in *`classes`* - don't know in advance *which object will call them*.

---

So there is a mechanism (implemented by a hidden parameter `this`) by which the object - when calling a method - secretively passes the address of *itself* to parameter `this`.

(In other programming languages may be used *other* names, as `Me` or `self`.)

Answer (score 0):

I would put it in points for you

1. When we create a new instance of a class then the non static methods and non static member fields are part of it. We access these methods and fields using `.` operator.
2. All the non static method or member fields has access to `this`. The `this` keyword simply is a reference to the current object upon which that method is executed upon.
3. Any class which implements `Iterable` interface can be used with enhanced `For-Loop`.
4. Enhanced for loop uses a syntax

`for (Object object : objectOfIterableType)`

If the class implementing `Iterable` interface is parametized, suppose its `E`. then its what you have to in your code.

```
    for (E x : this)
```

5. It means current class has the behaviour of being iterable and can be iterated on the collection of items it holds. Above statement will be executed for *each item in the collection of items of type E* represented by by the current object referred by `this` keyword. In each iteration `x` will represent an item from those contained items.