# A method declaration that includes 'this' as a variable name

Tags: java

I found that the following code compiles (Java 8), despite a wrong number of arguments and a usage of reserved keyword 'this'.

```
public interface Comparable<T> {
    public int compareTo(T o);
}


public class Person implements Comparable<Person> {

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Person this, Person other) {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

What is the reason for such behavior? Any code examples are welcome.

Comment: Did you define `Comparable` yourself?

Comment: `this` will always refer to the object that the method is attached to (the Person); you don't need to add a parameter for it. It looks like whatever you're trying to do is already done by java.

Comment: `method(ClassName this, other)` will be compiled same as `method(other)` if it belongs to `ClassName`. Some people (if I remember correctly coming from C++) like to explicitly add that parameter to show on which object it will be invoked. Possibly related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44095738/1393766

Comment: I just learned something new today. :)

Comment: It is useful if you want to add an annotation to the `this` variable.

Comment: In which way? Can you give an example?