# The thinking about String class's API

Tags: java, string, api, methods, invoke

The following codes are based on Java.
Here, the famous method "toUpperCase()", can be invoked like this:

```
String s = new String("abc");
String ss = s.toUpperCase();
//result: ss = "ABC"
```

For this: `s.toUpperCase()`
 We didn't pass a value to the method, so this method cannot has a meaningful return value.
To explain what is called a not-meaningful return value, here is an example:

```
//not pass a value to the method
String toUpperCase(){
...
return ???;
}
```

As above, the return value has no relationship with that object called "s". (the invoking of a non-parameter method is often independent from the objects). If I invoke this non-parameter method: `String ss = s.toUpperCase();` **how can that return a value that has any relationship with the object "s"**

And the following is called meaningful:

```
//pass a value to the method
static String toUpperCase(String str){
....  //to change the "str" into uppercase
return str;
}
```

Now I can invoke the method toUpperCase() like this:
`String ss = String. toUpperCase(s);`
 Since **I pass the "s" (its address) to the method, I can do anything I wish to change the object and return a meaningful return value.**

---

Based on the above, I have a reasonable doubt about this method `s.toUpperCase()`. since it cannot return a meaningful return value.

Comment: Do you understand the `this` reference?  _"the invoking of a non-parameter method is often independent from the objects"_ -- that is 100% false.  You are thinking of `static` methods.

Comment: `s` is an instance of `String`, which contains a series of `char`s which represent your text. `String#toUpperCase` is a instance method which acts upon the text of an instance of `String`, so it returns the contents of `s`, but converted to upper case. It's kind of a core fundamental of object oriented programming

Comment: No.  It is not *reasonable* doubt.  It is completely *unreasonable* doubt.  It is a plain fact that `toUpperCase()` actually works for **millions** of Java programmers.  So, if you have a *theoretical* argument that it shouldn't work, then the *reasonable* conclusion is that your argument is incorrect ... because there is something about Java that you don't understand.

Comment: What do you mean by "We didn't pass a value to the method"? Is your concern that `s.toUpperCase()` has no information about what instance it was invoked on (here held by `s` reference variable)? If that is the case then you need to know that this code will be compiled in something close to `String.toUpperCase(s);` (first argument for non-static method is reserved for instance of class which method belongs to, so `toUpperCase()` method is behind the scene more like `toUpperCase(String this){...}`) and inside it you can communicate with object represented by `s` via `this`).

Comment: In other words, `s.someMethod()` doesn't pass `s` explicitly, but behind the scenes it is compiled as `someMethod(s)`. Similarly `a.someMethod(b)` will be compiled as `someMethod(a,b)`. Maybe this will be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44095738

Answer (score 1):

First, terminology. `s` is an instance.

> how can that return a value that has any relationship with the object "s"

Do you understand `this`? For example, how does `dog.getName()` return a "meaningful value" of the name of that `dog` instance?

[The `char[]` of the `String` object named `s` is stored within that instance](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/lang/String.java#114), much like the `String name` of a `Dog` object.

```
class Dog {
    String name;

    public String getName() { return name; } // or 'return this.name;'
}
```

Bonus: [Source code of `toUpperCase()` implementation](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/lang/String.java#String.toUpperCase%28java.util.Locale%29), which does make a call to `Character.toUpperCase(c)` because `char` primitives to not have a `toUpperCase` method themselves.