# what is this loop doing?

Tags: loops, arraylist, processing

```java
void draw() {
  background(13);

  for (Line ml : middleLines) {//what kind of loop this is?
   ml.drawLine();
   ml.update();
}
```

what is this for loop doing can't undertstand.Can any-one help me?

Comment: See this: [Using Enhanced For-Loops with Your Classes](https://blogs.oracle.com/corejavatechtips/using-enhanced-for-loops-with-your-classes)

Comment: "what is this loop doing?" seems to be too general title - could make your question more specific

Answer (score 1):

[Lufritz's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47773880/873165) is correct, but I wanted to encourage you to Google this type of question.

Googling [for loop colon](https://www.google.com/search?q=for+loop+colon) returns a ton of results, including:

- ["Enhanced" For Loops](https://www.cis.upenn.edu/~matuszek/General/JavaSyntax/enhanced-for-loops.html)
- [Java: What does the colon (:) operator do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2399590/java-what-does-the-colon-operator-do)
- [Colon : in for{} loop?](https://coderanch.com/t/405709/java/Colon-loop)
- [The For-Each Loop](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/language/foreach.html)

If you ever see syntax you're not sure about, just Google that syntax. You'll find a ton of tutorials online, which should always be your first stop.

Answer (score 0):

This is a for-each loop. It iterates over every element in the given array. 
It is basically the same as this:

```
for (i = 0; i < middleLines.count; i++) {
    Line ml = middleLines[i];
    ml.drawLine();
    ml.update();
}
```

If you have to go over every element use for-each. It just saves lines of code.